# How to convert 'Functional Componenet' to 'Class Component' in React?

Tags: reactjs

I would like to convert this `Functional Component`

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/core/Menu';
import FacebookLoginButton from "./components/FacebookLoginButton"

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  menuButton: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
  },
  title: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
}));

function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <AppBar position="static">
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton edge="start" className={classes.menuButton} color="inherit" aria-label="menu">
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <Typography variant="h6" className={classes.title}>
            Tiket.hu
          </Typography>
          <Button color="inherit">Search</Button>
          <Button color="inherit">Basket</Button>
          <FacebookLoginButton/>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

to Class Component, like below here, but I get an error. Do you know what is wrong?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/core/Menu';
import FacebookLoginButton from "./components/FacebookLoginButton"

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  menuButton: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
  },
  title: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
}));

class App extends Component {
    classes = useStyles();
    render() {
      return <div className="App">
        <AppBar position="static">
          <Toolbar>
            <IconButton edge="start" className={this.classes.menuButton} color="inherit" aria-label="menu">
              <MenuIcon />
            </IconButton>
            <Typography variant="h6" className={this.classes.title}>
              Tiket.hu
            </Typography>
            <Button color="inherit">Search</Button>
            <Button color="inherit">Basket</Button>
            <FacebookLoginButton/>
          </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
      </div>;
    }
}

export default App;
```

Do you know what is wrong? How should I convert differently?

[image]

Comment: _"You can’t use Hooks **inside** of a class component, ..."_ [Source](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#should-i-use-hooks-classes-or-a-mix-of-both) . You still try to use `useStyles()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use the material ui HOC with a class component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/core/Menu';
import FacebookLoginButton from "./components/FacebookLoginButton"

// import this
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

// make this
const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  menuButton: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
  },
  title: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
})

class App extends Component {
    render() {
      return <div className="App">
        <AppBar position="static">
          <Toolbar>
            <IconButton edge="start" className={this.props.classes.menuButton} color="inherit" aria-label="menu">
              <MenuIcon />
            </IconButton>
            <Typography variant="h6" className={this.props.classes.title}>
              Tiket.hu
            </Typography>
            <Button color="inherit">Search</Button>
            <Button color="inherit">Basket</Button>
            <FacebookLoginButton/>
          </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
      </div>;
    }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(App);
```

Comment: Hi! Where I can learn more about this expression? `export default withStyles(styles)(App);` `withStyles` is a method, and `styles` and `App` are parameters? Sorry I am newbie in Node.js, React. :D

Comment: Hi! If I put `const { classes } = this.props;` out of `render()` I get an error. Shall I put in `render()`? But then I do not need `this.` in `this.classes.title` right?

Comment: Oh yes you can remove `this` and just use `classes.title` or `this.props.classes.title`

Answer (score 1):

Material-ui MakeStyles is using the hook pattern, which is not allowed inside class components. 
Use withStyles HOC instead.

```
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const styles = {
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  menuButton: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
  },
  title: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
};

class App extends Component {
    const { classes }  = this.props;
    the rest of your component...
}

export default withStyles(styles)(App);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `hooks` inside a `Class Component` this isn't allowed. Hooks are specifically made to work with `Functional Components`